# Dynamic pagination with Scroll in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 33 entries in json.
I have a code that tracks the scroll and loads new 10 entries.

If you set the scroll value to equal or less than zero, then everything works well, and when the scroll is at the bottom of the page, 10 new entries are added and the scroll rises. When the scroll again reaches the end of the page, 10 new entries are added again.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: true,
      currentItem: 0,
      totalLoading: 0,
      totalCount: 33
    };
  }

  loadingData() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      fetch('/api/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10, 'item': this.state.currentItem }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state.data, ...result.data, totalLoading: this.state.totalLoading + result.data.length });
          } else {
            this.setState({ data: result.data, totalLoading: result.data.length });
          }
        })
        .finally(() => this.setState({ isFetching: false }));
    }
  }

  scrollHadler = () => {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= 0 && this.state.totalLoading < this.state.totalCount) {
      this.setState({ isFetching: true, currentItem: this.state.currentItem + 10 });
      this.loadingData();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingData();
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }
```

But I need new 10 records to be added when the scroll is 250 - in this case, the code also works, but when scrolling to 250, ALL records are added at once (and only 10 records are needed at that moment).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: true,
      currentItem: 0,
      totalLoading: 0,
      totalCount: 33
    };
  }

  loadingData() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      fetch('/api/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10, 'item': this.state.currentItem }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state.data, ...result.data, totalLoading: this.state.totalLoading + result.data.length });
          } else {
            this.setState({ data: result.data, totalLoading: result.data.length });
          }
        })
        .finally(() => this.setState({ isFetching: false }));
    }
  }

  scrollHadler = () => {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= 250 && this.state.totalLoading < this.state.totalCount) {
      this.setState({ isFetching: true, currentItem: this.state.currentItem + 10 });
      this.loadingData();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingData();
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If you set exactly 250, then tracking the scroll values in the console - this does not always work ...
250 is the difference that corresponds to when the user reaches the start of the footer. I tried to implement this via ref, but it doesn't work ....
This means that I need the next 10 records to load when the user scrolls down 250 to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Problems in this part -  if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= 250 && this.state.totalLoading < this.state.totalCount) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution!

This code is working!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: true,
      currentItem: 0,
      totalLoading: 0,
      totalCount: 33
    };
  }

  loadingData() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      fetch('/api/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'limit': 10, 'item': this.state.currentItem }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state.data, ...result.data, totalLoading: this.state.totalLoading + result.data.length });
          } else {
            this.setState({ data: result.data, totalLoading: result.data.length });
          }
        })
        .finally(() => this.setState({ isFetching: false }));
    }
  }

  scrollHadler = () => {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= 250 && this.state.totalLoading < this.state.totalCount && !this.state.isFetching) {
      this.setState({ isFetching: true, currentItem: this.state.currentItem + 10 });
      this.loadingData();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingData();
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHadler);
  }
```

I need add && !this.state.isFetching in this place:

`if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= 250 && this.state.totalLoading < this.state.totalCount && !this.state.isFetching)`